# Media Info says wav file is truncated instead of showing the properties

Tags: visual-c++, mediainfo

I have written some data to a wav file along with the header. But when i play it using media player or VLC it does not play. When I open the same file using MediaInfo, it says 'IsTruncated: Yes' . what does this truncated mean and how to solve this.

Please help